# How to make a custom annotation that the type checker will recognize as str?

Tags: python

I want to use the argument annotation to define a parser for the argument.

Here is an example:

```
def parser(arg: str) -> str:
    return do_something(arg)

def foo(a: parser):
    # get arg's annotation and parse it
    return get_annotation(foo, "a")(a)
```

The problem is when I call the function with an argument of type `str` the type checker warns me that it's not of type `parser`.

```
foo("hello")
```

My question: How can I get the best of both worlds and use the annotation feature to get `parser` where the type checker will get `str`?
(Preferably without using `Union`)

Maybe if something like this could work:

```
def foo(a: parser[str]):
    # get arg's annotation and parse it
    return get_annotation(foo, "a")(a)

foo("hello") # this compiles without any warnings
```

Sort of like `Optional` or `Union` return one object but the type checker analyzes them as different objects.

Comment: Can you fill out your question with an [mcve]? It helps both potential answerers and folks looking for a similar solution.

Comment: That code snippet makes no sense. `parse` is undefined, `parser` isn't a type, `get_annotation(foo, "arg")` seems to be attempting to refer to an `arg` argument that `foo` doesn't have, there's no `bar` anywhere, etc. It's not at all clear what you were trying to do.

Comment: @user2357112 yea that's my bad on this one, I changed some names but forgot to change their references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.9 added the [Annotated](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) type, so you can do this:

```
def foo(a: Annotated[str, parser]):
    # a is of type str, but has parser as metadata
    pass
```